# Passport.js / Google OAuth2 strategy - How to use token on login for API access

Tags: javascript, express, google-api, passport.js, google-oauth

I am logging users in via their domain Google accounts using passport.js. This works great, but now I need to give this application access to a few Google API's (drive, sheets, etc).

When a user logs in, a message appears in the logs, that makes it seem like passport has all the required info:

```
info: [06/Jun/2019:21:24:37 +0000] "302 GET /auth/callback?code=** USER ACCESS TOKEN HERE **&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive HTTP/1.1" [46]
```

This is achieved by passing the appended scopes via passport.authenticate(), which presents the user with the "Grant access to these things on your Google account to this app?" screen :

```
//Initial auth call to Google
router.get('/',
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    hd: 'edmonds.wednet.edu',
    scope: [
      'email',
      'profile',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    ],
    prompt: 'select_account'
  })
);
```

However, when I go and try to call an API with something like:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});

router.post('/gsCreate', function(req,res,next){

  sheets.spreadsheets.create({
    // Details here.....
  });

});
```

I get nothing but errors (the current one is `debug: authClient.request is not a function`)

My question is: Is it possible for me to use a setup like this, asking the user to log in and grant permissions once, and then somehow save that to their user session via passport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can't use passport.js for three-legged oauth for APIs like Sheets or Drive.

Have a look at the Using [OAuth for web servers documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) instead.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but see below for the link that helped me the most

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question, but I was able to access Google Gmail API functionalities along with Passport.js user authentication by specifying 'scopes' using the following process.
First, create a file to setup the passport-google-strategy in nodejs as follows.

passport_setup.js

```
const passport = require('passport')
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20')
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require('path');
//make OAuth2 Credentials file using Google Developer console and download it(credentials.json)
//replace the 'web' using 'installed' in the file downloaded
var pathToJson = path.resolve(__dirname, './credentials.json');
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(pathToJson));


passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {

    const query = { _id: id }
    Users.findOne(query, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json(err);
        } else {
            done(null, user)
        }
    })
})

//create a google startergy including following details
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: config.installed.client_id,
        clientSecret: config.installed.client_secret,
        callbackURL: config.installed.redirect_uris[0]
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken,otherTokenDetails, user, done) => {
        
        //in here you can access all token details to given API scope
        //and i have created file from that details
        let tokens = {
            access_token: accessToken,
            refresh_token: refreshToken,
            scope: otherTokenDetails.scope,
            token_type: otherTokenDetails.token_type,
            expiry_date:otherTokenDetails.expires_in
        }
        let data = JSON.stringify(tokens);
        fs.writeFileSync('./tokens.json', data);


        //you will get a "user" object which will include the google id, name details, 
        //email etc, using that details you can do persist user data in your DB or can check 
        //whether the user already exists

        //after persisting user data to a DB call done
        //better to use your DB user objects in the done method

        done(null, user)
  
    })
)
```

Then create your index.js file in nodejs for API route management and to call send method of Gmail API.
Also, run the following command to install "google-apis"

```
npm install googleapis@39 --save
```

index.js

```
const express = require("express")
//import passport_setup.js
const passportSetup = require('./passport_setup')
const cookieSeesion = require('cookie-session');
const passport = require("passport");
//import google api
const { google } = require('googleapis');
//read credentials file you obtained from google developer console
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require('path');
var pathToJson_1 = path.resolve(__dirname, './credentials.json');
const credentials = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(pathToJson_1));


//get Express functionalities to app
const app = express();

// **Middleware Operations**//

//cookie encryption
app.use(cookieSeesion({
    name:'Reserve It',
    maxAge: 1*60*60*1000,
    keys: ['ranmalc6h12o6dewage']
}))

//initialize passort session handling
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use(express.json());    

//**API urls**//

//route to authenticate users using google by calling google stratergy in passport_setup.js 
//mention access levels of API you want in the scope
app.get("/google", passport.authenticate('google', {
scope: ['profile',
    'email',
    'https://mail.google.com/'
],
accessType: 'offline',
prompt: 'consent'
}))

//redirected route after obtaining 'code' from user authentication with API scopes
app.get("/google/redirect", passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {

    try {
        //read token file you saved earlier in passport_setup.js
        var pathToJson_2 = path.resolve(__dirname, './tokens.json');
        //get tokens to details to object
        const tokens = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(pathToJson_2));
        //extract credential details
        const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed

        //make OAuth2 object
        const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id,
        client_secret,
        redirect_uris[0])

        // set token details to OAuth2 object
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(tokens)
     
       //create gmail object to call APIs
       const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: oAuth2Client })

       //call gmail APIs message send method
       gmail.users.messages.send({
             userId: 'me',//'me' indicate current logged in user id
             resource: {
                raw: //<email content>
               }
        }, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err)
              throw err
            }
            console.log('Email Status : ' + res.status)
            console.log('Email Status Text : ' + res.statusText)
         })

        res.status(200).json({ status:true })
        
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }

})

app.listen(3000, () => { console.log('Server Satrted at port 3000') })
```

You can separate the routes in the index.js file to different files for clarity using **express.Router()**

If you want to call another Google API service just change this code segment and code below that;

```
   const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: oAuth2Client })
   gmail.users.messages.send(....Send Method internal implementation given above....)
```

For Google Drive:

```
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: oAuth2Client});
drive.files.list(...Refer "Google Drive API" documentation for more details....)
```

Comment: if this were to be deployed on something like AWS, would it still be ok to have the tokens in a tokens.json file? If not, how would you get the data like access_token and refresh_token?

Comment: I coded this to run in the localhost. If you are deploying in the AWS multiple users may hit the API. Therefore better to use a unique-id(obtain from DB) with **tokens.json** file name when creating it for each user. Like `fs.writeFileSync('./U789517_tokens.json', data)`. When again reading the token file use `var pathToJson_2 = path.resolve(__dirname, './U789517_tokens.json')`. Otherwise when multiple users are accessing the API **tokens.json** file will be replaced by each user.

Comment: would there be a way to avoid the use of files and instead use something like a session variable, or perhaps putting the token into a database?

Answer (score 0):

user835611 has the correct answer, as that page explains everything quite nicely. However, if you still need more, the below link really helped me to understand how this works.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#oauth2